# ¿Como llamar a tus modulos sin escribir la ruta?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

vine para preguntar algo que es bien comun pero que pocos explican
mi contexto es que quiero utilizar paquetes sin publicar al npm y para eso ya desarrolle mi libreria pero tengo unas dudas finales con respecto al node y como haces para "exportar" los modulos.

1. como defino el `package.json` del modulo ?
2. como exporto todos mis folderes del modulo en un `index.js` ?
3. como utilizo este folder modulo en otros proyectos sin publicarlo a npm ?

aqui les paso la relacion de mis archivos

```
> calculator/src/lib.js
import equations from './algebra/equations'
import system_equation from './algebra/system_equation'
...
export default { equations, system_equations }
```

```
> calculator/src/index.js
// no se como resolver el path para volverlo modulo exportable desde node_modules
const app = require('./lib')
module.exports = app
// este module exports no funciona y no se que hace
```

```
> calculator/package.json
{
  "name": "calculator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Complex Math Calculator",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
  ...
}
```

la cosa es que al final deberia llamarse como cualquier otra libreria que te instalaste

```
> otroProyectoX/app.js
import calc from 'calculator'
```

y no tener que hacer toda la ruta `../node_modules/calculator/dist/index`
alguien sabe como hacer esto?
les agradeceria si me pudieran explicar

Comment: Pregunta interesante, no uso casi `nodeJS` para esas cosas asi que yo tambien quiero saber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes alojar tu código en GitHub o GitLab, y agregar tu ruta en la dependencias o directamente con el comando `npm install`.

```
npm install git://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

O escribir en el `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "bar": "git://github.com/foo/bar.git"
}
```

Ahora bien si el repositorio tiene otro método de acceso tener en cuenta que la url se escribe de la siguiente forma.

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish>
```

Puedes seguir los siguientes ejemplos:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
npm install git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
npm install git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/custom_ident' npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git npm install
```

## Exportar Modulos.

Debes crear funciones y retornar objetó con nombre de los librerías que desees.

```
//main.js
const foo = function(){ return 'foo' }
const bar = function(beer) { return 'bar' + beer}

module.exports = {
    methodFoo: foo,
    otherMethodBar: bar,
};
```

En en el `package.json` de tu libreria.

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "author": "your <your@gmail.com>",
}
```